# Prestashop Adyen module

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I 'm trying to install the Adyen module, I got the module in this github: https://github.com/PrestaShop/adyen
And I uploaded into my FTP, but when I see on my PrestaShop panel this module does not show there.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong on guessing the exact problem without looking at the back office of your site myself. But can go to

Backoffice->Modules->modules

[image: select sort by: installed and uninstalled and enabled and disabled modules both options]

I hope this is the case and it helps